# React-Redux Hooks, After set inputValue to empty, is not re-render in the antD Input

Tags: reactjs, redux

**This is The Component Page**

```
function TodoList() {

    //All states
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const list = useSelector((state) => state.list);
    const inputValue = useSelector((state) => state.inputValue);

    //All founcations
    const changeInputValue = (e) => {
        const action = {
            type: 'changeInput',
            value: e.target.value
        }
        dispatch(action);
    }

    const clickBtn = () => {
        dispatch({ type: "addItem" })
    }
  return (
        <div className="page" style={{ margin: '10px' }}>
            <div>
                <Input
                    placeholder={inputValue}
                    style={{ width: '250px', marginRight: '10px' }}
                    onChange={changeInputValue}
                >
                </Input>
                <Button type="primary" onClick={clickBtn}>Add Task</Button>
            </div>
            <div style={{ margin: '10px', width: '300px' }}>
                <List bordered dataSource={list} renderItem={item => (<List.Item>{item}</List.Item>)} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**And this is the my reducer for handle AddItem dispatch**

```
 if(action.type === 'addItem'){
        let newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
        newState.list.push(newState.inputValue);
        newState.inputValue = '';
        return newState;
    }
```

after action 'addItem' be dispatch into the reducer, I push the new input to the list and reset the input to `""` the item added to the list show up in my page, but Input is be reset to empty(However is `""` in store)

Comment: I think you need to make Input a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) that means you need to give it an onChange and a value property so `value={inputValue}` is missing. Your way of updating state is extremely inefficient, maybe [this](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) helps. You can do: `{...state, list:[...state.list, state.inputValue],inputValue:'']}`

Comment: Thanks a lot. it was really helpful!